# continuous of minimum

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $\Omega$ be an closed bounded and connected domain in $R^n$ and $h(x,t)$ is continuous in $\Omega\times [0,T]$.Let
$$
H(t)=\min_{x\in\Omega} h(x,t)
$$
How to prove $H(t)$ is continuous ?

What I try :
Assume $H(t)=h(x,t)$ and $H(t_0)=h(x_0,t_0)$ ,then 
$$
|H(t)-H(t_0)| = |h(x,t)-h(x_0,t_0)|  \\
=|h(x,t)-h(x,t_0)+h(x,t_0)-h(x_0,t_0)|  \\
\le |h(x,t)-h(x,t_0)|+ |h(x,t_0)-h(x_0,t_0)|   \\
\le c|t-t_0|+ |h(x,t_0)-h(x_0,t_0)|   \\
\le c|t-t_0| + c'|x-x_0|
$$
Then how to deal $ |x-x_0|$?

Comment: @RickSanchez  I don't know how to start , give me some hint ?

Comment: Well, what's $|H(t) - H(t+\Delta t)|$?  Can you make this depend only (or mostly) on $h(x,t) - h(x,t+\Delta t)$?  Maybe use the triangle inequality to wedge two copies of the same thing between those two $h(-,-)$s...

Comment: could you think of a counterexample when $\Omega$ is not bounded? How do you know that $\min$ is well-defined in the statement of your problem? It could be that $h(x,t)$ is not bounded below, or that it is bounded but $\min$ is not attained. How is one supposed to interpret your question in this case?

Comment: @Mirko  You are careful, I always mistake on the detail, maybe ,replace  open by closed is suitable .Sorry.

Comment: @EricTowers I still have some difficult . I add what I try in my question.

Comment: hint. for each $t$ pick $x_t$ such that min over $\Omega\times\{t\}$ is attained at $(x_t,t)$. If $t_n\to t$ (with $t_n\not=t$) then the sequence $x_{t_n}$ has a convergent subsequence. WOLOG $x_{t_n}\to x$ for some $x$ (as $n\to\infty$). Do something with $h(x,t)$ I do not know what but it ought to work.

Comment: Random question:  What would one do if the minimum of $h$ were not unique?  For instance, what if $h$ has a global lower bound and constantly takes the value of that lower bound on some rectangle $\Omega \times [a,b]$?

Comment: @EricTowers (if your comment was meant to relate to mine) We could pick a convergent subsequence (of any sequence) using compactness of $\Omega$. The limit $x$ will end up more of less a random point in the rectangle inside $\Omega\times\{t\}$ in which min is attained. I haven't thought out all details, don't know if connectedness will be relevant and if so, how.

Comment: @Mirko : I'm more concerned about the minimum continuing on from the rectangle from one of its corners.  A sequence that has been wandering around in the rectangle need not be anywhere near the special corner when it finally has to leave the rectangle...

Comment: @EricTowers if min is attained everywhere in the rectangle, then the corner won't be special. If the corner is special, i.e. the min at the corner is "better" than "min" elsewhere, then the sequences shouldn't be wandering too much, but better go to that corner. But I admit I do not quite follow, and I will think more, trying to make sense (or rather I will not, as I need to do something else soon).

Comment: @Mirko: Studying what happens for the situation that the minima are attained on the set $\{(z,z) \subset [0,1]^2 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1\} \cup ([1/3,2/3]\times[1/3,2/3])$ as $t$ crosses $2/3$ from below clarified what was going on (and I posted the results below).  This is what worried me.  For sequences allowed to linger around $(2/3 - \delta,1/2)$ as $t$ slowly marched upward, the sudden jump to $(2/3+\epsilon, 2/3+\epsilon)$ was worrisome.  I was imagining non-equicontinuous steepening as $x$ increased along the $t=2/3$ boundary of the rectangle.  Happily, that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $\Omega \times [0,T]$ is compact, so $h$ us uniformly continuous. I.e., for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that $|h(x,t) - h(x_0,t_0)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $|t-t_0| < \delta$.

> For each $t_0 \in [0,T]$, there is an $x_0 \in \Omega$ where $H(t_0) = h(x_0,t_0)$.  So, from the above observation about uniform continuity, because $h(x_0,t) \geq H(t)$, we have \begin{align}  H(t_0) > h(x_0,t) - \varepsilon \geq H(t) -  \varepsilon  \end{align} for all $t$ with $|t - t_0| < \delta$.  Symmetrically, $H(t) > H(t_0) - \varepsilon$.  Hence, $|t - t_0| < \delta$ implies $|H(t) - H(t_0)| < \varepsilon$.  Therefore, $H(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: what do you mean by $h(x_0,t) \ge H(t)$, how do you derive it? Which variable is fixed here, is $x_0$ fixed, and this inequality valid for all $t$, or is $t$ fixed and that valid for all $x_0$? Something doesn't seem to match when I read the definitions, $h(t)$ was supposed to be minimal value of $H(x,t)$ over all $x$ (for any fixed $t$, as it appears from the definition).

Comment: @Mirko : What's the definition of $H(t)$?  Can any $h(\xi,t)$ be less than $H(t)$?  Note that the two uses of $t$ are bound to the same value under specialization (which we avoid as much as possible).